# Unicorn speed and pickup problem

Tags: honda, motorcycle, unicorn

I purchased used unicorn bike  3 months ago. Its speed gets decreased suddenly on elevation road and pick up is not good at all. Please advise regarding this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please provide more information about what's going on. As it stands, could be a dozen different things. What have you tried to do to fix it? Is this new behavior, or has it always been like this? Have you pulled out the sparkplug to see how it looks? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: What exactly is a unicorn bike?